# How to restrict a collection to store only specific types of objects?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, xmlserializer

I have a property in the class which is used as a reply type of the operation contract in WCf service which communicates to the legacy ASMX clients.

```
 [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Person), Namespace = "TestNamespace")]
        [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Department),
            Namespace = "TestNamespace")]
        public Collection<object> OrgCollection { get; set; }
```

But if the consumer adds some other type than expected types, service crashes because `XmlSerializer` fails to serialize this property.

Is there a way to have a collection of some specific types? Generics would be the answer to it but instead of implementing a new collection class altogether, can I "inherit" my new class from some existing collection class so that all the functionality would be available to me?

Comment: Do you need to implement some Collection<T>, where T can be one of some classes?

Comment: @JooLio : I want to implement some Collection<T1, T2> where T1 & T2 can be of some classes.

Comment: Then use `where` clause, e.g. `public class LimitedCollection<T> where T : BaseType`

Comment: @CSharpLearner, I've edited my answer according to your comment. If it is not answer to the question, please, explain your problem more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a System.Collections.Generic.List for a collection of a specific type. You can also inherit from List to add your own functionality if you want to.

Comment: I want a "single" collection which is capable of storing objects of some specified types. List<T> allows me to store only one type of objects. There is workaround by having multiple Lists but better if I have only such a property.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [System.Collections.Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx) namespace.

According to your comment **"I want a "single" collection which is capable of storing objects of some specified types."**:
Create some middle class `A`:

```
class A<T1, T2> {}
```

and then use:

```
List<A<T1, T2>> OrgCollection { get;set }
```

or use the `Tuple<T1, T2>` class (.NET 4.0).